# int not being properly recognized as an int from a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Python 3.8 using Pandas, reading in from csv file. The code snippet below works in detecting if one of the fields in the projectID column is not an int. The problem is when there is a projectID that is NOT an int, the error message displays the first projectID rather than the ID causing problems, even if it itself is an int.

ex. projectIDs reads in IDs [1, 3, 5]. It runs like a champ. No errors.

ex. projectIDs reads in IDs [1, 3, a5]. Program terminates saying "projectID 1 is not an integer".

How can I correct this?

```
# load projects csv file
projectsFileData = pd.read_csv(projectsFile)

for i in projectsFileData['projectID']:
    if not type(i) == int:
        sys.exit("ERROR: projectID {0} is NOT an integer. Terminating Program.".format(i))
```

Comment: What is the "expected behavior"?

Comment: for the second example, expected behaviour is - Program terminates saying "projectID a5 is not an integer

Comment: Because `pandas` will just read the entire column as a string. The first project id *is not an `int`* (note, in actuallity, pandas uses numpy.dtypes under the hood, but iterating over the column will cast wrap each item in a native python type rather than a numpy dtype) What are you asking exactly? Correct *what*?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what happens if a `print(i)` statement is put before the `if`.

Comment: Just tried it, Mike. Interesting result: it prints out only the first value, 1, before terminating the program even though a5 is the problem child. If I make sure all values are ints, it prints all of them out, without any errors.

Comment: @blindside044 yes, **because the entire column is converted to string** , i.e. `dtype=object`, unless the entire column can be converted to a numeric dtype.

Comment: Thanks Juanpa. Originally your first comment didn't make sense to me but now I see it =P ...now to find a way to convert each into an array of individual integers

Comment: If the whole column is a string, you know there's a problem somewhere; then you can iterate through them and try to pass them to the `int()` function to see which ones raise an exception.

The other way would be to tell Pandas which types you expect in each column; then it would report the error itself, but you'd have less control over how the error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try type connversion:
ex:

```
s = "10010"

# printing string converting to int base 2 
c = int(s,2) 
print ("After converting to integer base 2 : ", end="") 
print (c) 

# printing string converting to float 
e = float(s) 
print ("After converting to float : ", end="") 
print (e)
```

according to your question int(i,10), 10 is the base of the expected value

```
projectsFileData = pd.read_csv(projectsFile)

for i in projectsFileData['projectID']:
if not type(int(i,10) == int:
    sys.exit("ERROR: projectID {0} is NOT an integer. Terminating Program.".format(i))
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the datatype to string for the column `projectID`:

```py
projectsFileData = projectsFileData['projectID'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC I think something like this is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def str_int_chooser(string):
    return int(string) if string.isnumeric() else string

csv = """projectIDs, Name
1, Project Runway
2, Project Alpha
3, Astronomical-Society
4a, Necronomicon-con"""

csv_file = StringIO(csv)

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, converters={"projectIDs": str_int_chooser})

print(df)
for i in df["projectIDs"]:
    print(i, type(i))
```

Output:

```
  projectIDs                   Name
0          1         Project Runway
1          2          Project Alpha
2          3   Astronomical-Society
3         4a       Necronomicon-con
1 <class 'int'>
2 <class 'int'>
3 <class 'int'>
4a <class 'str'>
```